# Domain Driver Design after passing controller in another thread context lost. (Dot Net Core)

Tags: .net-core, domain-driven-design, dbcontext, dispose

In my DDD dot net core projects all service instance created .
at the end of controller method, started a thread of action method in same controller.
But when the method start to get data it lost context.
[image]

How can I stop disposing context. or any other way to bypass it